# How to show facebook comments box multiple times on a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I have a page for a bakery site, and on the page, there will be a list of cakes. There will be a picture of the cake, followed by a comments box, to let people comment on that specific cake. Each cake will need to have its own set of comments, separate from each other.

But unless I'm mistaken, facebook comment plugin is linked to a page's url, and can't be shown multiple times?

Is there any way to show it multiple times per page, and to link it individually to each cake, so the comments don't mix up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But unless I'm mistaken, facebook comment plugin is linked to a page's
>   url, and can't be shown multiple times?

It can be shown.Though it is linked with your site url,you always have the privilage of appending custom string after the ternerary operator in your URL.

> Is there any way to show it multiple times per page, and to link it
>   individually to each cake, so the comments don't mix up?

The trick here is to make a url unique.

This can be done in various ways:

```
1)www.something.com#commentbox1

2)www.something.com?section=commentbox1
```

I am using this on my current website where there are more than 10 comment boxes:http://www.arrowlife.com/

Comment: Is it possible to create the moderation service for each comment box then? Should it be created manually for each new article? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to unique anchor tags per product, you may also add the product ID in a query string such as www.yoursite.com?productID=44

In my case I was dynamically creating a div showing the product detail.  It was also necessary to force the Facebook script to show the comment section using the [FP.XFBML.parse command](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)